# How to subscribe consumer to N number of unknown queues?

Tags: python, queue, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I'm trying to understand how to do this:

Some producers creates N number of queues ( lets say `foo.1 foo.2 foo.3` ). Than I have one consumer on another part of the Rabbit that needs to get messages from all N (in my example 3 ) queues. I know I can do something like this:

```
(method_frame, header_frame, body) = self.channel.basic_get(queue='foo.1', no_ack=False)
(method_frame, header_frame, body) = self.channel.basic_get(queue='foo.2', no_ack=False)
(method_frame, header_frame, body) = self.channel.basic_get(queue='foo.3', no_ack=False)
```

But what if my consumer doesn't know the names, what I would really like to do is something like:

```
(method_frame, header_frame, body) = self.channel.basic_get(queue='foo.*', no_ack=False)
```

Comment: Is there any way you could use 1 queue but separate bindings created by the producer?

Comment: A second ago asked similar question =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RabbitMQ admin interface/api will have access to all of the queues on the server. There is an easy to use Python client [PyRabbit](http://pyrabbit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that will let you [get_queues](http://pyrabbit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#pyrabbit.api.Client.get_queues). From there you can do whatever filtering you require.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I see:
You need to get all the messages from a provided number `n` of queues. From my personal experience, I would just write a for loop and create a string by adding `"foo.%s" % (iteration)`.

Here is an example to what I mean:

```
for i in range(queues):
    str = 'foo.%s' % (i)
    (method_frame, header_frame, body) = self.channel.basic_get(queue=str, no_ack=False)
```

As long as you know the number of queues, then you can use this.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, but my problem is I don't know ( or better to say don't want to know the queues names, I was thinking that the can be created "on the fly" and my consumer will grab them ) But thanks any way

Answer (score 1):

If your consumer has a way of recognizing a queue you should be able to find them all by searching through `foo.__dict__`.

You should keep in mind that if any of your queues are set at the class level, then they will not appear in `foo.__dict__`. In this case you will have to write an algorithm that traverses `foo`'s mro.

Alternatively if you can modify the creation of queues you can track them through the use of a sort of manager.

```
class MyQueue(list):
    queues = {}  # Keeps track of all the queues out there

    @classmethod
    def add_to_producer(cls, obj, name, init_values):
        q = MyQueue(init_values)
        cls.queues[(obj, name)] = q
        setattr(obj, name, q)


class MyProducer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize our producer with a couple of queues
        MyQueue.add_to_producer(self, 'a', [1,2])
        MyQueue.add_to_producer(self, 'b', [])


p1 = MyProducer()
p2 = MyProducer()
# Add another queue to p2
MyQueue.add_to_producer(p2, 'c', [4,5,6])

# Go through all of our created queues
for obj, attr_name in MyQueue.queues:
    if obj == p1:
        print 'p1', getattr(obj, attr_name)

    if obj == p2:
        print 'p2', getattr(obj, attr_name)

>>> p1 [1, 2]
>>> p1 []
>>> p2 [4, 5, 6]
>>> p2 [1, 2]
>>> p2 []
```

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate your time, spending on answering this question.